# Unable to get property 'onMessage' of undefined or null reference in Edge extension content script

Tags: javascript, browser-plugin, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm converting an Chrome extension which works well to Edge extension, and I need to have message listener in my content script.

Here is the code in my content script:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(listener);

function listener(message) {
    console.log(message);
}
```

However, each time script executes, I get this error, pointing to first line of my content script code:

```
Unable to get property 'onMessage' of undefined or null reference
```

I've tried changing browser.runtime into chrome.runtime, but nothing changes.

Here I've found that Edge supports runtime.onMessage with some minor incompatibilities:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/api-support/supported-apis/

Comment: You may want to provide more details about your extension, like how do you send the message and what manifest file looks like. Also, you could check https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8473140/ and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes I've checked that issue before posting question and it didn't help. I don't see a reason for providing more details and making it more complicated than it is, because it's obvious that script gets injected into page, but crashes on first line, being unable to get reference to browser.runtime

Comment: _"because it's obvious that script gets injected into page"_ And yet, it may help to see how exactly. Is it from a manifest entry? Is it programmatic injection?

Comment: It's manifest defined content-script.

Comment: @kecman Please add the manifest entry then. Mask out urls with `example.com` if needed.

Comment: Just see you (or other people) have reported this issue on [Edge Issue Tracker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9823671/), we may want to wait for Edge team to confirm if it's a bug.

Comment: @Xan 
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.example.com/*","https://*.example.com/*"],
      "js": ["js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js","js/cs.js"],
      "all_frames":true
    }